# Why is Google Chrome not seen in the Screen Recording Options in Security and Privacy settings

Tags: security, catalina, google-chrome, privacy, screen-sharing

I recently upgraded to Catalina(which I regret now). I have been facing lot of weird issues after upgrading one of which being not able to share the screen on Google Hangout Meet. I followed a few of the approaches mentioned in other forums.

The fix was simple where I have to go the **System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Screen Recording** and make sure Google Chrome is checked.

The issue for me, though, is that I am not seeing "Google Chrome" on the list when I go to the Screen Recording section and I have no idea how to make Google Chrome seen on the list. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: hi @soluve, has chrome asked for screen recordings permission? you can reset permissions using `tccutil` also, if you want.

Comment: We have a full guide to [configure screen recording permission in macOS Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384228/18101) and also a guide to [reset screen recording permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384230/18101) when it's not working right.

Comment: @John M's suggestion below (installing the Screen Recorder extension to Chrome) works quickly and easily

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome must first ask for the access.  At that time it will show up here unchecked, unless you selected "allow" at the time that it asked.

As @ankii mentioned `tccutil` will allow you to reset your permissions, but you will require the bundle id of the app in question.

**To get the bundle id**

```
% osascript -e 'id of app "Google Chrome"'
com.google.Chrome
%
```

From there you can reset Chrome's permissions using `tccutil`

**Reset permissions**

```
% tccutil reset ALL com.google.Chrome
%
```

At this point, if Chrome wants to do anything that would require explicit permission from you, it will have to ask again.  It has the permissions as though you had installed it for the first time.

Comment: I tried this but maybe I did something wrong that's why it didn't work for me. However, I found another way to do this.

launchctl list | grep -i chrome

tccutil reset All com.google.Chrome

This worked like a charm for me.

Thanks for pointing me towards the right direction.

Comment: @SuloveBista You need to quit and re-open Google Chrome after running tccutil. That's probably why this answer didn't work for you.

Comment: `tccutil: Failed to reset ALL approval status for com.google.Chrome`

but worked after a restart, thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

Visit https://meet.google.com/

Start a meeting, then cast your screen

Then you'll prompt the permission window.

[image]

After that, it'll appear in the `Screen Recording` section.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue where Google Chrome was not showing up on the list at all. Turns out that there was a pending request from another app that was in the background, still waiting for me to "Open System Preferences" or "Deny". Once I cleared that out, the system prompt for Google Chrome showed up.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Holy reboot solved the problem. And during the reboot process I saw another app's dialog for screen recording permissions, just as you said.

Comment: How did you "clear it out"?

Comment: @wordsforthewise I "cleared it out" by accepting the system prompt that I did not see because it was behind a bunch of apps

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue, where "Cast..." was not correctly asking for the "Screen Recording" permission. Rebooting, `tccutil`, and other tricks did not work for me - instead, I installed a [Screen Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-recorder/hniebljpgcogalllopnjokppmgbhaden?hl=en) extension which asked for the permission. Once it was granted, "Cast..." worked fine and I was able to uninstall the extension.

**Edit** - I [filed a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1139695) in Chromium's bug tracker, and it looks like it wasn't correctly requesting the permission. A fix has been committed so should be fixed soon!

Answer (score 0):

For if you find this problem through Google, I found another solution:

Make sure you start the application from **finder** and not a third party program.

Applications started showing up in System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Screen Recording again **but only when I used finder to start the application**

*10.15.7 Catalina*