# Google meet can't share screen or window on Mac

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason I'm unable to share a window or full screen on Chrome with Google Meet on Mac. Versions:

- Chrome: Version 99.0.4844.74 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Mac: Monterey 12.3

In the Mac settings under security, screen recording is enabled for Chrome. I've tried restarting Chrome, restarting the computer, disabling and enabling screen recording for Chrome from the settings (with Chrome restarts in between) but nothing seems to work. The screen sharing also doesn't work for google meet (the app).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing, then re-adding, Chrome to the list of apps? [This question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382564/why-is-google-chrome-not-seen-in-the-screen-recording-options-in-security-and-pr?rq=1) may have some answers.

Comment: Removing and adding it back does not solve the problem, nor reinstall. This specific version has an issue.

Comment: Removing and adding it again worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If the recent google updates to 99.0.4844.83 (Official Build) don’t fix this bug for you, here is a repair workaround for the changes made to the app:

1. Quit Chrome
2. `tccutil reset ScreenCapture com.google.Chrome` in Terminal

Manually added Chrome:

1. Open **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy Tab** > **Screen Recording** (option on lefthand side)
2. Click the lock at the bottom to make changes
3. Click the + and add `/Applications/Google Chrome`

Relaunch Chrome.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue with the exact same Browser and MacOS versions. I was wondering if maybe it was a known issue in Chrome and they had a fix in an upcoming version, so I downloaded the [Chrome Beta version](https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/) (Version 100.0.4896.45 (Official Build) beta (x86_64)) and it worked for me. Very strange.

Comment: We experienced the same issue and the Beta version did work!

Comment: Yes! Confirmed this works.

Comment: This works! BLESS YOU!

Comment: Using the beta version (100.0.4896.45) also worked for me - thanks for the suggestion! Normal Chrome was version 99.0.4844.83 (latest update). These are two different apps, so it's possible "normal" Chrome has some corrupt files somewhere that are causing this issue.

Comment: Issue is still persistent on chrome version Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (arm64) on m1 mac

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue but updated to the latest version of Chrome (99.0.4844.83 (Official Build) (arm64)) and issue gone

Answer (score 0):

Login to google accout in **Safari browser** and then try to share screen on Google meet. It will work. It has an issue with Google Chrome in Mac.

Comment: Interesting...  I have the exact opposite experience.  I have to use Chrome when using Google Meet (Chrome 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (arm64))  (same Chrome 99.... version on my Intel Mac.)  Safari will join a meeting but my audio and video are all horked up.   Chrome is the only browser Have found on a Mac that works fully with Google Meet.

Comment: @TheWellington Did you try to share screen or window on Google meet in Google Chrome?

Comment: Yes.   I use screen share daily, and have used window sharing occasionally

Comment: Then it might have an issue, in particular, the Google Chrome version only. I Hope Chrome will resolve in an upcoming release.

Comment: Do you know how to share a tab or a specific window only (as opposed to entire screen) with Google Meet in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behavior. It Version 99.0.4844.74 (Official Build) (arm64) and it still there. Unfortunately, from Safari you cannot share a "window" from another application. So, I have to go to Firefox to get this option.

It doesn't work in Chrome. The problem became consistant after the last OS update. Prior this, it was erratic (a complete restart of the computer OR a "Force Quit") of google chrome did the job. Now, Chrome is unable to share windows altogether.

Comment: The .83 minor minor minor version update should fix this without needing the workaround / repair.

Comment: I just updated .83 right now and I can confirm that this fixes the issue! Great discovery

Comment: Confirming that .83 does not fix it for me.